# Formula of the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi i}{2n})}{n}$$
Any ideas on how to evaluate this? Basically, I need to find a limit from this sum, when $n \to \infty$ and the only approach I see is to find a formula from this sum.

Comment: $$\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  i}{2 n}\right)}{n}=\frac{\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{4 n}\right)+1}{2 n}$$

Answer (score 3):

By the definition of the definite integral$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin(\frac{\pi i}{2n}) = \int_0^1\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}dx = -\frac 2\pi\cos\frac{\pi x}{2}\bigg|_0^1=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Also, see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Connection_with_integration).

---

If you really want to find a formula for your sum, see [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407003/sum-of-sum-k-1n-sink-theta). This should help.

Comment: Your solution just awesome, but I came to this sum exactly from integral, so I need another solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Prox I didn't type the full solution, but the link provided should help if you don't mind incorporating complex numbers.